# Minimal amount of edges needed to be removed to make a graph triangle free (approximation algorithm)

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph G = (V,E) there is a minimal number of edges - k - that need to be removed to make G triangle free. I'm trying to find an approximation algorithm (that is as efficient as possible) that finds a set of edges to remove to make G triangle free that is no larger than 3k. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you show us your efforts? Did you try the greedy algorithm, for example?

Comment: By greedy algorithm I assume you mean looping through all possible triangles on the graph and removing edges from them as they come. But that won't work. for example you can have a single edge that is part of n-2 triangles (where n is the numbers of vertices) but instead of removing that edge the algorithm will remove n-2 other edges.

Comment: No, my greedy approach would be to compute the number of triangles containing the edge $e$ for all $e\in E$. Then pick the edge that is contained in the biggest number of triangles. Remove it. Iterate. Not sure this works, just asking if you tried it.

Comment: So "greedy" is meant in the sense that in each step we eliminate as many triangles as possible.

Comment: yes, that seems to work, thanks

Comment: I write it as an answer then, so that you can accept it (and the post can be concluded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the greedy algorithm: in each step, eliminate the biggest possible number of triangles by deleting the edge contained in the most triangles.